# My R function is returning an incorrect result when invoked by Renjin

Tags: renjin

If I invoke my R script's compute_score function in R studio, the geography score returned is 68.18, which is what I expect. However when I invoke the same function in Renjin it is returning 60.0, which is incorrect. I have used the exact same value for the function argument in both cases. Any idea what could be causing this? Is there any chance this could be a Renjin bug?

The end of my compute_score function looks like this...

```
compute_score <- function(CIF)
{
   ...

    response = list(
        geographyScore = as.numeric(geographyScore),
        industryScore = as.numeric(industryScore),
        productScore = as.numeric(productScore),
        channelScore = as.numeric(channelScore),
        clientTypeScore = as.numeric(clientTypeScore),
        transactionScore = as.numeric(transactionScore),
        tags = tags
     )

   return(response)
}
```

And I invoke it in my Java class using the following lines of code...

```
ScriptEngine engine = new RenjinScriptEngineFactory().getScriptEngine();
File file = new File(getClassLoader().getResource("sample_interface.R").getFile());
engine.eval(new java.io.FileReader(file));
ListVector resList = (ListVector) engine.eval("compute_score(" + buildRRequest(buildRequest(ACCOUNT_HOLDER, NP_RETAIL, ISO_SWISS, ISO_WESTERN_SAHARA, false)) + ")");
```

And this is what resList evaluates to when I check in Intellij debugger:

```
list(geographyScore = 60.0, industryScore = 75.0, productScore = 100.0, channelScore = 50.0, clientTypeScore = 25.0, transactionScore = 100.0, tags = list())
```

All the other fields return correctly other than geography, that should definitely be 68.18182, would someone have any idea why it isn't?

Just to remind you, passing in the exact same value when invoking the function in RStudio gives me 68.18182, invoking the same function with the same argument value using renjin's eval operation gives me a score of 60.0, at first glance it looks like it is rounding but Im not so sure, any help would be appreciated greatly.

Comment: could you provide the code that is used to calculate geographyScore?

Comment: If you cannot share the source code which leads to the result for `geographyScore`, then you should try to break the code down into smaller steps or add logging (e.g. by adding lots of `cat()` statements) to pinpoint where the difference originates. Then, you can construct a smaller example which is reproducible.